# How to fit image any Devices in JqueryMoblie

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I have 1 image (1081*1921) that I am trying to display on different screen sizes.

```
<img src="images/2 copy.jpg" alt="" height="100%" width="100%"/><br/>
```

But it does not fit mobile screens.

So please give me any idea about Image fit to any Mobile height or any Browser height.

Comment: What does it mean when you say "But it does not fit some screens"? It's not fitting how?

Comment: @Gajotres i jest tried image fit any mobile height but i don't know how to fit image any mobile so please give me any idea

Answer (score 0):

Apply this to your css:

```
img { max-width:100%; }
```

This will change the width to a maximum of 100% (device width)

Comment: Why would you do that? Height is on auto by default. Doesn't make sense to apply all default rules to a class.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `height` and `width` attributes and use

```
 max-width: 100%;
```

this will make sure your browser shows the entire image.

Answer (score 0):

hi dear friends please check it this Link [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jR74w/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="res-image-wrapper">
 <img src="http://www.ukafh.co.uk/communities/4/004/008/327/664//images/4581542034.jpg" />  </div>
```

**CSS**

.res-image-wrapper{

> ```
> max-width:90%;
> height:auto;
> position: relative;
> display:block;
> margin:0 auto; }
> ```

.res-image-wrapper img{

> ```
> max-width:100% !important;
> height:auto;
> display:block;
> ```
>
> }

Comment: thanks for replay your code nice   but when a run your code on mobile  it's add scroll but i want fit any mobile screen with out any scroll please give me any idea